# Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :photos association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms

I am implementing multiple photo upload for a model and so I am using paperclip and nested_form gems

A Property has many photos.

This is Property model.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photos_attributes, :type, :price, :address, :desc, :category_id, :location_id, :user_id
  TYPE = {
    rent: "rent",
    sale: "sale"
  }

  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: lambda { |t| t[:photo].nil? }, allow_destroy: true
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

This is photo model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :property_id
  belongs_to :property, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :photo, styles: {small: "100x100>", medium: "300x300>"},
                    url: "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    path: ":rails_root/public/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_size :photo, less_than: 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png", "image/pjpeg"]
end
```

And my slim view is

```
= nested_form_for @property, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  = f.fields_for :photos do |photos_f|
     = photos_f.label :photo
     .file-field-wrap
       .file-field
         = photos_f.file_field :photo
         = photos_f.link_to_remove "Remove"
        = photos_f.link_to_add "Add", :photos  # this line gives error
```

Error is 
`Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :photos association.`

When I run `Property.new.attributes.keys` on console it doesn't show `:photos_attributes` as a key. It shows `["id", "type", "price", "address", "desc", "created_at", "updated_at", "category_id", "location_id", "user_id"]`

I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing a line that gives an error to the following:

```
= f.link_to_add "Add", :photos
```